# How to debug inconsistencies resulting from combinations of declarations not covered in the CSS spec?

Tags: css

The two screenshots below show the huge difference between Chrome 31's (on the left) and Safari 6's renditions of the same HTML+CSS (given at the end of this post).  The page may be viewed [here](http://www.panix.com/~kynn/safari-bug.html).  NB: no JS is used by this page.

[image]
[image]

One possible explanation for this wide discrepancy is that the stylesheet for this page includes *some combination* of declarations that is not covered by the CSS specification, meaning that each browser is free to interpret it arbitrarily.  (In this case, for example, the "out-of-spec combination" may be the pair of declarations `max-width: 400px;` and `display:table;` for the `.main` selector.)

Question: **Is there some automated way to detect such "out-of-spec" combinations of declarations?**

It is worthwhile to note that the example given here may be *relatively* easy to diagnose by inspection (at least for someone with a very thorough command of the CSS spec), but it's no stretch to imagine situations in which such "out-of-spec" combinations may arise much more subtly (e.g. by interactions between declarations in separate stylesheets, etc.).  Therefore, some tool to identify such "out-of-spec" combinations would be a huge help.

The only tool I could think of for this sort of thing was [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net), but it does not pick up anything in the CSS that may lead to fixing the discrepancy illustrated above.

---

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  font-family:consolas,monaco,courier,monospace;
}

.banner{
  background:lightgray;
}
.header{
  height:50px;
}
.footer{
  height:300px;
}

.main{
  position:relative;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:10px;
  display:table;

  background-color:steelblue;
}

.left-panel{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#555;
}
.vfloat{
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px 30px;
  background-color:#0aa;
  font-size:15px;
}

.right-panel{
  margin-left:200px;
}
.vfixed{
  padding:20px 60px;
  background-color:orange;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```
<div class="header banner"></div>

<div class="main">

  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="vfloat"><p>Donec laoreet, justo eget luctus pulvinar, nulla mauris facilisis massa, sit amet egestas lacus erat eu felis. In at urna eu elit dictum porttitor. Ut dictum justo nec urna mattis, ut pharetra mauris adipiscing. Pellentesque lacinia turpis id vulputate commodo. Nullam fringilla justo vitae consequat euismod.</p></div>
  </div> <!-- .left-panel -->
  <div class="right-panel">
    <div class="vfixed"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque magna lacus, sed porttitor tortor ultricies ut. Quisque tellus lectus, tincidunt et elementum a, viverra non diam.</p></div>
  </div> <!-- .right-panel -->

</div> <!-- .main -->

<div class="footer banner"></div>
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, strangely enough I get this in Safari 6.1: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/QJiuM2N.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

You have a container with `display:table`. You should therefore have elements with `display:table-row`, and `display:table-cell`. But you don't. And then you wonder why it renders weird...

Comment: Aside from the fact that you didn't try to answer the question being asked, this particular situation has [very well-defined behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes).